# Sorting by keyword

Tags: sorting, keyword

I have a group of pictures that toggle back and forth on 2 different pages so far.  Now, I'd like to be able to sort by keywords.  I like to be able to bring up a page only with items starting with letter A or bring up only a group with pictures relating to sports only, fruit only etc.  If someone could point me in the right direction to get started, I would appreciate it.  Thanks

http://readautism.atwebpages.com/
http://readautism.atwebpages.com/index1.html

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="ISO-8859-1" />
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=Edge,chrome=1">
<title>Example of How to Play a Sound on Click or on MouseOver</title>


<script>
var gStorage = {};

function toggle(anImage, anAltSrcArr) {
    if (typeof(anImage) === "undefined" || typeof(anAltSrcArr) === "undefined" || anAltSrcArr.length === 0) {
        return;
    }

    var id = anImage.id;
    var oldSrc = anImage.src;

    if (typeof(gStorage[id]) === "undefined") {
        gStorage[id] = {
            'id': id,
            'origSrc': oldSrc,
            'i': 0
        };
    }

    gStorage[id].i += 1;
    if (gStorage[id].i > anAltSrcArr.length) {
        gStorage[id].i = 0;
    }

    if (gStorage[id].i === 0) {
        anImage.src = gStorage[id].origSrc;
    } else {
        anImage.src = anAltSrcArr[gStorage[id].i - 1];
    }
}
</script>
<script>
var html5_audiotypes={ //define list of audio file extensions and their associated audio types. Add to it if your specified audio file isn't on this list:
    "mp3": "audio/mpeg",
    "mp4": "audio/mp4",
    "ogg": "audio/ogg",
    "wav": "audio/wav"
}

function createsoundbite(sound){
    var html5audio=document.createElement('audio')
    if (html5audio.canPlayType){ //check support for HTML5 audio
        for (var i=0; i<arguments.length; i++){
            var sourceel=document.createElement('source')
            sourceel.setAttribute('src', arguments[i])
            if (arguments[i].match(/\.(\w+)$/i))
                sourceel.setAttribute('type', html5_audiotypes[RegExp.$1])
            html5audio.appendChild(sourceel)
        }
        html5audio.load()
        html5audio.playclip=function(){
            html5audio.pause()
            html5audio.currentTime=0
            html5audio.play()
        }
        return html5audio
    }
    else{
        return {playclip:function(){throw new Error("Your browser doesn't support HTML5 audio unfortunately")}}
    }
}

//Initialize two sound clips with 1 fallback file each:

var mouseoversound=createsoundbite("whistle.ogg", "whistle.mp3")
var clicksound=createsoundbite('http://static.sfdict.com/staticrep/dictaudio/P05/P0501900.mp3', "whistle.ogg")
var uniquevar1=createsoundbite("http://static.sfdict.com/staticrep/dictaudio/B01/B0147400.mp3")
var uniquevar2=createsoundbite("http://static.sfdict.com/staticrep/dictaudio/R01/R0153700.mp3")
var uniquevar3=createsoundbite("http://static.sfdict.com/staticrep/dictaudio/B01/B0130100.mp3")
var uniquevar4=createsoundbite("http://static.sfdict.com/staticrep/dictaudio/C02/C0298100.mp3")
var uniquevar5=createsoundbite("http://static.sfdict.com/staticrep/dictaudio/C08/C0897400.mp3")
var uniquevar6=createsoundbite("http://static.sfdict.com/staticrep/dictaudio/H00/H0020400.mp3")
var uniquevar7=createsoundbite("http://static.sfdict.com/staticrep/dictaudio/H01/H0110100.mp3")
var uniquevar8=createsoundbite("http://static.sfdict.com/staticrep/dictaudio/C05/C0578600.mp3")
var uniquevar9=createsoundbite("http://static.sfdict.com/staticrep/dictaudio/S05/S0555400.mp3")
var uniquevar10=createsoundbite("http://static.sfdict.com/staticrep/dictaudio/R04/R0433000.mp3")
var uniquevar11=createsoundbite("http://static.sfdict.com/staticrep/dictaudio/T01/T0107200.mp3")
var uniquevar12=createsoundbite("http://static.sfdict.com/staticrep/dictaudio/P02/P0230400.mp3")
var uniquevar13=createsoundbite("http://static.sfdict.com/staticrep/dictaudio/N02/N0227500.mp3")
var uniquevar14=createsoundbite("http://static.sfdict.com/staticrep/dictaudio/L00/L0050400.mp3")
var uniquevar15=createsoundbite("http://static.sfdict.com/staticrep/dictaudio/S04/S0462700.mp3")

</script>

</head>
<body
<p><CENTER><FONT SIZE = 4>DIRECTIONS: CLICK A PICTURE TO SEE WORD, THEN CLICK WORD TO SEE PICTURE AGAIN.</FONT>

<img class="with-action" id="image1" name="image1" src="bat.jpg" onclick="uniquevar1.playclip();toggle(this, ['bat1.jpg'])" STYLE="position:absolute; TOP:95px; LEFT:70px; WIDTH:175px; HEIGHT:175px"/>
<img class="with-action" id="image2" name="image2" src="refrigerator.jpg" onclick="uniquevar2.playclip();toggle(this, ['refrigerator1.jpg'])" STYLE="position:absolute; TOP:95px; LEFT:370px; WIDTH:175px; HEIGHT:175px"/> 
<img class="with-action" id="image3" name="image3" src="baseball.jpg" onclick="uniquevar3.playclip();toggle(this, ['baseball1.jpg'])" STYLE="position:absolute; TOP:95px; LEFT:670px; WIDTH:175px; HEIGHT:175px"/>
<img class="with-action" id="image4" name="image4" src="chair.jpg" onclick="uniquevar4.playclip();toggle(this, ['chair1.jpg'])" STYLE="position:absolute; TOP:95px; LEFT:970px; WIDTH:175px; HEIGHT:175px"/>
<img class="with-action" id="image5" name="image5" src="couch.jpg" onclick="uniquevar5.playclip();toggle(this, ['couch1.jpg'])" STYLE="position:absolute; TOP:95px; LEFT:1270px; WIDTH:175px; HEIGHT:175px"/>
<img class="with-action" id="image6" name="image6" src="hair.jpg" onclick="uniquevar6.playclip();toggle(this, ['hair1.jpg'])" STYLE="position:absolute; TOP:395px; LEFT:70px; WIDTH:175px; HEIGHT:175px"/>
<img class="with-action" id="image7" name="image7" src="hat.jpg" onclick="uniquevar7.playclip();toggle(this, ['hat1.jpg'])" STYLE="position:absolute; TOP:395px; LEFT:370px; WIDTH:175px; HEIGHT:175px"/> 
<img class="with-action" id="image8" name="image8" src="clown.jpg" onclick="uniquevar8.playclip();toggle(this, ['clown1.jpg'])" STYLE="position:absolute; TOP:395px; LEFT:670px; WIDTH:175px; HEIGHT:175px"/>
<img class="with-action" id="image9" name="image9" src="sink.jpg" onclick="uniquevar9.playclip();toggle(this, ['sink1.jpg'])" STYLE="position:absolute; TOP:395px; LEFT:970px; WIDTH:175px; HEIGHT:175px"/>
<img class="with-action" id="image10" name="image10" src="rug.jpg" onclick="uniquevar10.playclip();toggle(this, ['rug1.jpg'])" STYLE="position:absolute; TOP:395px; LEFT:1270px; WIDTH:175px; HEIGHT:175px"/>
<img class="with-action" id="image11" name="image11" src="teeth.jpg" onclick="uniquevar11.playclip();toggle(this, ['teeth1.jpg'])" STYLE="position:absolute; TOP:695px; LEFT:70px; WIDTH:175px; HEIGHT:175px"/>
<img class="with-action" id="image12" name="image12" src="pencil.jpg" onclick="uniquevar12.playclip();toggle(this, ['pencil1.jpg'])" STYLE="position:absolute; TOP:695px; LEFT:370px; WIDTH:175px; HEIGHT:175px"/> 
<img class="with-action" id="image13" name="image13" src="nose.jpg" onclick="uniquevar13.playclip();toggle(this, ['nose1.jpg'])" STYLE="position:absolute; TOP:695px; LEFT:670px; WIDTH:175px; HEIGHT:175px"/>
<img class="with-action" id="image14" name="image14" src="lamp.jpg" onclick="uniquevar14.playclip();toggle(this, ['lamp1.jpg'])" STYLE="position:absolute; TOP:695px; LEFT:970px; WIDTH:175px; HEIGHT:175px"/>
<img class="with-action" id="image15" name="image15" src="shoe.jpg" onclick="uniquevar15.playclip();toggle(this, ['shoe1.jpg'])" STYLE="position:absolute; TOP:695px; LEFT:1270px; WIDTH:175px; HEIGHT:175px"/>

</p></CENTER>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here are three functions:

- Select by keyword
- Select like first letter
- Select similar pictures

Are these functions you looking for?

```js
var pics = [
    {id:0, name: 'Pineapple', tags: ["sport", "food"], audio:'B01/B0147400.mp3', img:'chair1.jpg'},
    {id:1, name: 'Venus', tags: ["sport", "planet"], audio:'B01/B0147400.mp3', img:'chair1.jpg'},
    {id:2, name: 'Jupiyer', tags: ["water", "food"], audio:'B01/B0147400.mp3', img:'chair1.jpg'},
    {id:3, name: 'Baseball', tags: ["color", "food"], audio:'B01/B0147400.mp3', img:'chair1.jpg'},
    {id:4, name: 'Apple', tags: ["car", "planet"], audio:'B01/B0147400.mp3', img:'chair1.jpg'},
    {id:5, name: 'Cloud', tags: ["plant", "sport"], audio:'B01/B0147400.mp3', img:'chair1.jpg'},
    {id:6, name: 'Computer', tags: ["tree", "fruit", "stone"], audio:'B01/B0147400.mp3', img:'chair1.jpg'},
];
  
function select(keyword) {
    return pics.filter(function(p){
       return (p.tags && p.tags.indexOf(keyword)>-1); 
    });  
}

function selectLike(pic) {
   var res = {};        
   for(var i=0; i<pics.length;i++) {
       select(pic.tags[i]).forEach(function(simpic){
           res[simpic.id] = true;
       });
    };
    delete res[pic.id];  
    return Object.keys(res).map(function(key){ return pics[key] });
}


function selectByLetter(letter) {
    return pics.filter(function(p){
       return (p.name[0].toUpperCase() == letter.toUpperCase()); 
    });  
};

function prepareAudioClips() {
    pics.forEach(function(p){
        p.clip = createsoundbite("http://static.sfdict.com/staticrep/dictaudio/"+p.audio)
    });
}

// This is like a sceleton of the function
function generateHTMLforSimilar(arr) {
    s = '';
    for(var i=0;i<arr.length;i++) {
        s += '<img class="with-action" id="'+arr[i].name+'" name="'+arr[i].name+'" src="'+arr[i].img+'" onclick="pics[arr.id].clip.playclip();toggle(this, [\"'+arr[i].img+'\"])" STYLE="position:absolute; float:left; WIDTH:175px; HEIGHT:175px"/>';
    }
    return s;
}

  
document.write( "<b>Like keyword:</b> ", JSON.stringify(select("food")) ,'<br/>');
document.write( "<b>Like letter:</b> ", JSON.stringify(selectByLetter("A")) ,'<br/>');
document.write( "<b>Like picture:</b> ", JSON.stringify(selectLike(pics[0])) ,'<br/>');

// prepareAudioClips();   // This wont work at SO without resource files
document.write( "<b>HTML:</b> ", generateHTMLforSimilar(selectLike(pics[0])) ,'<br/>');
```

Comment: Do you know what else I would have to add besides your code to get this working?  I'm pretty much a novice.

Comment: Unfortunately, it is a long story... I would start with: 1. Extend the 'pics' objects array with all parameters, including picture name, audio clip source file. 2. Write the HTML generation procedure, which can generate HTML code to place all pictures (with all attributes) on the screen. 3. Add dblclick() function to search all related pictures and rearrange them on the screen. I will add couple lines to the code to explain the idea.